# Python - parameters sometimes yes and sometimes no

Tags: python, tkinter

this code must move a triangle when you press enter. My answer is correct but I don't really understand this.

Watch the line inside option 1-> `def mov()` this should work when i call it but it isn't.

Now lets go option2 again lets go-> `def mov(A)` look I have a parameter there (`A`) but this parameter does not have any conection with something, then why it isn't work with my option 1? its not the same thing? 
How can I know when I must use an auxiliary parameter like that?

**OPTION 1 -FAIL**

```
from Tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=400,height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10,10,10,60,50,35)
def mov():
  canvas.move(1,5,0)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>',mov)
```

**OPTION2 -WORK**

```
from Tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=400,height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10,10,10,60,50,35)
def mov(A):
  canvas.move(1,5,0)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>',mov)
```

Comment: the `bind_all` simply **expects a method that takes a parameter**.

Comment: even if this method dont work with it? how you know when another method like bind_all is going to need other method who takes a parameter?

Comment: yes because the caller cannot know that.

Comment: how you know when another method like bind_all is going to need other method who takes a parameter? BTW thanks for ur answer sry if my english sucks

Comment: because `bind_all` calls internally `bind` over the whole application as is specified [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [`bind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) (`bind_all` is a wrapper around `bind` as is documented [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), it forwards to `bind` over the entire application):

> The `bind` method from the widget command allows you to watch for
>   certain events and to have a callback function trigger when that event
>   type occurs. The form of the bind method is:
>
> **`def bind(self, sequence, func, add=''):`**
>
> where:
>
> - `sequence`: is a string that denotes the target kind of event. (See the bind man page and page 201 of *John Ousterhout*’s book for details).
> - `func`: is a Python function, **taking one argument**, to be invoked when the event occurs. An Event instance will be passed as the
>     argument. (Functions deployed this way are commonly known as
>     *callbacks*.)
> - `add`: is optional, either `''` or `'+'`. Passing an empty string denotes that this binding is to replace any other bindings that this
>     event is associated with. Passing a `'+'` means that this function is to
>     be added to the list of functions bound to this event type.

(copied, boldface added)

So the `func` needs to take **one argument**. Since the ***caller* cannot know** whether the *callee* will use the argument or not, every function you bind with `bind` or `bind_all` has to have **exactly one argument**. That argument contains **the event parameters**: for instance which key is pressed, etc.

In other words it is a *contract* that you provide a function with one argument, and you need to respect these contracts. Whether the argument is used or not is of no importance for Tkinter.